# Vue & Vuex getter array filter causes error online only

Tags: vue.js, vuex, computed-properties

I can't get the frontend to render my computed property. Whatever I tried the last days, it fails.locally everything renders fine, online I get the error.
Anyone ever had this issue? it seems u can't make a getter based on another getter with array.filter !?

Vuex index.js

```
    state: {
    posts: [],
},
```

my getters

```
  posts: state => state.posts,
postsNews: state => {
    return state.posts.filter(post => post.category.description === 'News').slice(0, 3);
},
```

computed

```
 computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['postsNews', 'posts']),
```

the frontend

```
       <div v-if="posts && posts.length" class="hidden md:flex  flex-wrap -mx-2    mt-5">
                <div class="flex flex-wrap">
                    <ArtikelCard class="cursor-pointer w-1/2"
                                 v-for="(post, index) in postsNews" :key="index"
                                 :post="post"/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

my mutation:

```
   [SET_POSTS] (state, payload) {

    state.posts = payload;
},
```

my action

```
    getPosts ({ commit, getters }, payload = '') {
    commit(TOGGLE_LOADER, { condition: true });

    axios.get(`${API}/posts/paginated?${payload}`, headers(getters))
        .then(response => {
            commit(SET_POSTS, response.data.data);
            console.log(response.data.data);

        }).catch(error => {
        unauthenticated(error.response.status, commit);
        commit(TOGGLE_LOADER, { condition: false });
        consoleDev('getPosts', error);
    })
        .finally(() => commit(TOGGLE_LOADER, { condition: false }));
},
```

the error ...

```
chunk-vendors.433933fc.js:7 TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of null
at app.9a6615b5.js:1
at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
at postsNews (app.9a6615b5.js:1)
at O.t._wrappedGetters.<computed>.t._wrappedGetters.<computed> (chunk-vendors.433933fc.js:13)
at kr.<anonymous> (chunk-vendors.433933fc.js:13)
at nr.get (chunk-vendors.433933fc.js:7)
at nr.evaluate (chunk-vendors.433933fc.js:7)
at kr.postsNews (chunk-vendors.433933fc.js:7)
at Object.get [as postsNews] (chunk-vendors.433933fc.js:13)
at a.n.<computed> (chunk-vendors.433933fc.js:13)
```

Comment: The error tells you that `post.category` returns null: are you sure `state.posts` is an array of objects, which in turn contains a property/key called `category`? If it is being populated by a call to an endpoint/API, inspect that it is indeed returning the expected payload.

Comment: *it seems u can't make a getter based on another getter with array.filter* - you can. Whatever the problem is, it originates in a place where `posts` is assigned, not in the code you posted.

Comment: Please look at the additional output information in the original post

Answer (score 0):

Locally it works - console

```
(35) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
```

[Console output locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WxGe.png)

```
  {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Pt]
```

0:
id: (...)
file: (...)
file_type: (...)
file_conversions: (...)
title: (...)
slug: (...)
text: (...)
preview_text: (...)
external_link: (...)
author: (...)
category: Object
id: (...)
description: "Software"
slug: (...)
constant: (...)
color_code: (...)

but online it doesn't -thats why im so annoyed. can't find the issue unless I deploy to staging:

```
chunk-vendors.433933fc.js:7 TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of null
at app.eea11d3b.js:1
at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
at postsNews (app.eea11d3b.js:1)
at O.t._wrappedGetters.<computed>.t._wrappedGetters.<computed> (chunk-vendors.433933fc.js:13)
at kr.<anonymous> (chunk-vendors.433933fc.js:13)
at nr.get (chunk-vendors.433933fc.js:7)
at nr.evaluate (chunk-vendors.433933fc.js:7)
at kr.postsNews (chunk-vendors.433933fc.js:7)
at Object.get [as postsNews] (chunk-vendors.433933fc.js:13)
at a.n.<computed> (chunk-vendors.433933fc.js:13)
```